# Assembly 32bit write to file after creating one

Tags: assembly, output, masm, 32-bit, irvine32

Well, I guess I do not get the process of writing to a file after creating it. I am a beginner at this, so help with this assignment will be huge to me.

> Description (Symmetric Encryption): 
>     1. Encoding         a. Ask the user to type some text       b. Ask the user to type a private key within this range [1-255]. Perform the range
>   validity checking.        c. Encrypt the input text using the provided
>   private key, put the cipher text in a file named by the user.
>     2. Decoding         a. Ask the user to specify the file to decode.      b. Load the cipher text from that file and try to descrypt it without
>   assuming the private key is the same
>            one used in encoding.        c. Put all the trial results in a seperated file named by the user.         d. Figure out what the most
>   reasonable result (or original plaintext) is.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
BUFMAX = 128                    ; maximum buffer size
KEYMAX = 128                    ; maximum buffer size
BUFFER_SIZE = 5000

.data
sPrompt BYTE        "Enter some text message:       ", 0
keyPrompt   BYTE        "Enter a private key [1-255]:       ", 0
cFile   BYTE        "Enter a filename for cypher text: ", 0
sEncrypt    BYTE        "Cypher text                    ", 0
sDecrypt    BYTE        "Decrypted:                 ", 0
error   BYTE        "The key must be within 1 - 255!    ", 0
buffer  BYTE         BUFMAX + 1 DUP(0)
bufSize DWORD    ?
keyStr  BYTE         KEYMAX + 1 DUP(0)
keySize DWORD    ?
key     DWORD    ?
filename    BYTE        "newfile.txt                    ", 0
fileHdl DWORD   ?
bufFile BYTE        BUFFER_SIZE DUP (?)
textMsg DWORD   ?

.code main PROC
call InputTheString             ; input the plain text
call InputTheKey                ; input the security key
call CypherFile             ; input a cypher filename
;call TranslateBuffer           ; encrypt the buffer
;mov edx, OFFSET sEncrypt           ; display encrypted message
;call DisplayMessage
;call TranslateBuffer           ; decrypt the buffer
;mov edx, OFFSET sDecrypt           ; display decrypted message
;call DisplayMessage
exit

main ENDP

InputTheKey PROC
pushad                      ; save 32-bit registers

LK: mov edx, OFFSET keyPrompt ; display a prompt call WriteString ; Enter a private key [1-255] call Crlf ; start a new line call ReadInt ; read int into system mov key, eax ; store int into keyStr cmp eax, 255 ; compare newly read int ja LC ; jump if above 255 to LC cmp eax, 1 ; compare newly read int jb LC ; jump if below 1 to LC jmp LR ; if between range jump to LR LC: mov edx, OFFSET error ; The key must be within 1 - 255! call WriteString ; Display the error call Crlf ; start a new line loop LK ; loop back to enter the security key LR: popad ; restore the registers ret InputTheKey ENDP

CypherFile PROC pushad mov edx, OFFSET cFile ; "Enter a filename for cypher text call WriteString ; Enter a name for encrypted file call Crlf ; Start a new line mov edx, OFFSET bufFile mov ecx, BUFMAX call ReadString ; Store the filename in eax mov edx, OFFSET bufFile call CreateOutputFile ;pop eax mov eax, fileHdl mov edx, OFFSET textMsg ;mov ecx, BUFFER_SIZE call WriteToFile popad call CloseFile ret
;mov filename, eax
;mov edx, OFFSET filename
;push eax
;mov eax, fileHdl
;mov edx, OFFSET bufFile
;mov ecx, BUFFER_SIZE
;mov edx, "C:\outputtext.txt"

;mov edx, OFFSET filename
;mov ecx, SIZEOF filename
;push eax
;mov eax, bufSize
;call WriteToFile

CypherFile ENDP

InputTheString PROC
pushad                      ; save 32-bit registers
mov edx, OFFSET sPrompt         ; display a prompt
call WriteString                ; "Enter some text message"
call Crlf                       ; start a new line
mov ecx, BUFMAX             ; maximum character count
mov edx, OFFSET buffer          ; point to the buffer
call ReadString             ; input the string
mov textMsg, eax
mov bufSize, eax                ; save the length
popad
ret

InputTheString ENDP

DisplayMessage PROC
pushad
call WriteString
mov edx, OFFSET buffer          ; display the buffer
call WriteString
call Crlf
call Crlf
popad
ret

DisplayMessage ENDP

TranslateBuffer PROC
pushad
mov ecx, bufSize                ; loop counter
mov esi, 0                  ; index 0 in buffer
mov edi, 0                  ; index 0 in the key

L1: mov al, keyStr[edi] ; get a character from encryption key xor buffer[esi], al ; translate a byte inc esi ; point to next byte inc edi ; go to next position in key cmp edi, keySize ; compare if equal to size of the key jb L2 mov edi, 0 ; reset to beginning of the key L2: loop L1 popad ret TranslateBuffer ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Forgot to put on that the library files are located here: http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/examples/index.htm

Comment: What is the problem?  You have to tell us what you expect to happen, and what happens instead of the expected output.

Comment: I expect it to write text to the created output file. What it is not doing is writing text to the file, even after the file has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are blindly just putting things together.

Irvine includes the source for all of his functions, they include comments as to what parameters they take.
`WriteToFile` takes 3 parameters -
`eax` == the file handle to write to
`edx` == pointer to buffer that contains data to write to file
`ecx` == length of data to write to file.

`CreateOutputFile` already returns a file handle in `eax` but you are overwitting it with `mov eax, fileHdl`
you are setting `edx` correctly, now the size of data to write, `ReadString` returns this in `eax`
You also have `popad` in the wrong place.

```
call    ReadString ; Store the filename in eax 
push    eax                 ; save string length

mov     edx, OFFSET bufFile 
call    CreateOutputFile 
mov     hFile, eax          ; save file handle
pop     ecx                 ; restore string length into ecx
mov     edx, OFFSET textMsg 
call    WriteToFile 

mov     eax, hFile          ; move hfile into ecx
call    CloseFile 
popad 
ret
```

See the difference?

You have other problems also.  Your cypher does not work.

Comment: Blindly is the correct keyword there! I do not understand assembly language very well, but trying to learn it. Yesterday is the first time asking for help online and everyone has been very helpful. I did not know that edx can store the textMsg to write to the file. I thought eax handled that.

Comment: I see what you mean by the cypher not working. It encrypts the filename instead of the textMsg.

Comment: So, how does the encrypted message end up in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you didn't get it working?  Well, I was bored, so cleaned up your code, and fixed a few things.  I did not let you off that easily though, I added a small bug in the code somewhere, so you cannot submit the correct code/output file.

Kip, writes a good book for beginners.  He does not use the full features of MASM though.  For beginners, the great thing about MASM is its `invoke` macro.  It does checking on the called proc parameters and catches MANY errors.

In your other post, you were missing parameters to a call right?  Well, if you used invoke with `WriteToFile`, then MASM would of caught that and told you.  But I guess he doesn't show that?

Anywhoo, try this:

```
INCLUDE d:\irvine32\Irvine32.inc
includelib d:\irvine32\irvine32.lib
includelib d:\irvine32\kernel32.lib
includelib d:\irvine32\user32.lib
BUFMAX = 128                                ; maximum buffer size
BUFFER_SIZE = 5000

.data
sPrompt     BYTE    "Enter some text message: ", 0
keyPrompt   BYTE    "Enter a private key [1-255]: ", 0
cFile       BYTE    "Enter a filename for cypher text: ", 0
sEncrypt    BYTE    "Cypher text: ", 0
sDecrypt    BYTE    "Decrypted: ", 0
error       BYTE    "The key must be within 1 - 255!", 0

.data?
bufSize     DWORD   ?
key         DWORD   ?
bufFile     BYTE    BUFFER_SIZE DUP (?)
buffer      BYTE    BUFMAX + 1 DUP (?)

.code 
main PROC
    call    InputTheString                  ; input the plain text
    call    InputTheKey                     ; input the security key

    call    TranslateBuffer                 ; encrypt the buffer

    mov     edx, offset sEncrypt
    call    WriteString

    mov     edx, OFFSET buffer              ; display encrypted message
    call    WriteString
    call    Crlf

    call    CypherFile 

    call    TranslateBuffer                 ; decrypt the buffer

    mov     edx, offset sDecrypt
    call    WriteString

    mov     edx, OFFSET buffer              ; display encrypted message
    call    WriteString
    call    Crlf

    call    WaitMsg
    exit

main ENDP

InputTheString PROC
    mov     edx, OFFSET sPrompt             ; display a prompt
    call    WriteString                     ; "Enter some text message"

    mov     ecx, BUFMAX                     ; maximum character count
    mov     edx, OFFSET buffer              ; point to the buffer
    call    ReadString                      ; input the string

    push    offset buffer
    call    Str_length
    mov     bufSize, eax                    ; save the length   
    ret
InputTheString ENDP

InputTheKey PROC

PromptForKey:
    mov     edx, OFFSET keyPrompt           ; display a prompt 
    call    WriteString                     ; Enter a private key [1-255] 
    call    ReadInt                         ; read int into system 
    test    eax, eax
    jz      BadKey
    cmp     eax, 255
    jg      BadKey

    mov     key, eax
    ret

BadKey:
    mov     edx, OFFSET error               ; The key must be within 1 - 255! 
    call    WriteString  
    call    Crlf
    jmp     PromptForKey
InputTheKey ENDP

CypherFile PROC 
    mov     edx, OFFSET cFile               ; "Enter a filename for cypher text 
    call    WriteString                     ; Enter a name for encrypted file 

    mov     edx, OFFSET bufFile 
    mov     ecx, BUFMAX 
    call    ReadString                      ; Store the filename in eax 

    mov     edx, OFFSET bufFile 
    call    CreateOutputFile 
    push    eax                             ; save file handle

    mov     ecx, bufSize      
    sub     ecx, 5         
    mov     edx, OFFSET buffer 
    call    WriteToFile 

    pop     eax                             ; restore file handle
    call    CloseFile 
    ret
CypherFile ENDP

TranslateBuffer PROC
    mov     ecx, bufSize
    mov     eax, key
    xor     esi, esi
XorByte:
    xor     buffer[esi], al
    inc     esi
    cmp     esi, ecx
    jne     XorByte
    ret
TranslateBuffer ENDP

DisplayMessage PROC

    mov     edx, OFFSET buffer          ; display the buffer
    call    WriteString
    call    Crlf
    call    Crlf
    ret

DisplayMessage ENDP
END main
```